# Terraform: Correctly assigning a static private IP to newly created instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

Objective:

I'm trying to create a number of EC2 instances and assign them each a static private ip address from a map variable. This address must be the primary address, and basically means I'm not using the DHCP assigned address provided by aws.

Issue:

The terraform plan succeeds, and I can create instances which show the static IP address assigned, *together* with the DHCP assigned address (in the aws console). When I ssh into the instance I see the primary address is the DHCP assigned address. there is a second ENI attached to the instance (eth1) but the static ip address is not there.

The Question:

How to have terraform create the instance, using the statically assigned IP address for the primary interface (eth0), instead of the default assigned DHCP address? Basically, how can I either:

a) Create this interface with statically assigned interface at instance creation time or,
b) Replace the existing primary interface IP address with a static one (or the entire ENI itself with a newly created one with the static IP address)

Here are the details:

I am using the module as follows in a separate main.tf file:

a) create the instance

```
module "ec2-hadoop-manager" {
  source                      = "../modules/ec2"
  ami_id                      = "${var.dw_manager["ami"]}"
  instance_type               = "${var.dw_manager["instance_type"]}"
  aws_region                  = "${var.region}"
  availability_zone           = "eu-west-1a"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  role                        = "hadoop-manager"
  env                         = "${var.environment}"
  vpc                         = "${var.vpc_id}"
  security_group_ids          = "${var.aws_security_group_id["sg_id"]}"
  key_name                    = "${var.key_name}"
  subnet_id           = "${var.default_subnet}"
  number_of_instances = "${var.dw_manager["count"]}"
}
```

b) I'm Assigning private IPs to the instance using a resource (outside the module bloc in main.tf):

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "private_ip" {
    count = "${var.dw_manager["count"]}"
    subnet_id = "${var.default_subnet}"
    private_ips = ["${lookup(var.dw_manager_ips, count.index)}"]
    security_groups = "${var.aws_security_group_id["sg_id"]}"
    attachment {
        instance = "${element(split(",", module.ec2-hadoop-manager.ec2_instance_ip), count.index)}"
        device_index = 1
    }
}
```

NOTE: I have tried changing device_index to 0, but as expected, aws complains that there is already an eni attached at index 0:

```
Error applying plan:

3 error(s) occurred:

* aws_network_interface.private_ip.0: Error attaching ENI: InvalidParameterValue: Instance 'i-09f1371f798c2f6b3' already has an interface attached at device index '0'.
        status code: 400, request id: ed1737d9-5342-491a-85a5-e49e70b7503d
* aws_network_interface.private_ip.2: Error attaching ENI: InvalidParameterValue: Instance 'i-012bda6948bbe00c9' already has an interface attached at device index '0'.
        status code: 400, request id: 794c04fb-9089-4ad0-8f5d-ba572777575a
* aws_network_interface.private_ip.1: Error attaching ENI: InvalidParameterValue: Instance 'i-00ac215801de3aba8' already has an interface attached at device index '0'.
```

### status code: 400, request id: cbd9e36d-145f-45d4-934f-0a9c2f6e7768

Some additional information that may be useful: Link to my full module definition files:

main definition file for the ec2 module:

http://pastebin.com/zXrZRrQ5

main outputs.tf definition file for ec2 module:

http://pastebin.com/9t5zjfQS

Comment: Reference to a similar issue for context: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2998

Comment: I'm having same issue, however I've also tried a slightly different method, which makes sense to me - define the aws_network_interface as normal, but then in the aws_instance set the network_interface property accordingly. Still doesn't work, but feels more intuitive than the way you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terraform v0.9.4 shipped with a new feature on `aws_instance` that let's you assign to device index 0, via a new config option `network_interface`:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#network-interfaces

There's also the [aws_network_interface_attachment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/network_interface_attachment.html), but I believe you want the new `network_interface` option for `aws_instance` above.

Example config:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "foo" {
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.my_subnet.id}"
  private_ips = ["172.16.10.100"]
  tags {
    Name = "primary_network_interface"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
    ami = "ami-22b9a343" // us-west-2
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    network_interface {
     network_interface_id = "${aws_network_interface.foo.id}"
     device_index = 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you actually want to do what you're doing. From your description I would expect a single network interface with a "static" IP.

Now what *I* would do is use the [`private_ip`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#private_ip) parameter of `aws_instance`, which simply sets the fixed IP for an EC2 host. Done.

What you seem to try is to create the host without a static IP in the `aws_instance` (you didn't show it, so I just assume), which will IMHO always give the host a dynamic IP. Then you create a second network interface, which you give a static IP, and attach it to the host. This will not be the first (or "primary") interface of the instance, but it has a static IP, and according to your description this is what happens.

I am pretty sure you will always end up with a DHCP IP address when you don't specify your static IP in your host definition.

So either you provide more information about your use case, or more code, but the way you do things is just wrong for what you want if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old, but I had something useful to add. The address for an EC2 instance is *always* from DHCP. AWS uses DHCP reservations to assign IP addresses. The only difference between a dynamically assigned address and "static" private address is that in the former AWS is randomly picking from the available addresses for the reservation and in the latter you're picking it. The way it gets applied is exactly the same for both, so you'll never see a static IP on the box.